# jQuery click event is called wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I' ve this problem only with firefox. I' ve a function called by click event on a button tag but this is called also when I pick an option from my select tag. Anyone knows how handle?

**jQuery**

```
$("#search").click(function () {
        var color = $("#selectedColor").html();
        console.log("color to be sended -> " + color);
        var input = $("<input type='hidden' id='color' name='color' value='" + color + "'/>" );
        $("#form").append(input);
        $("#form").submit();
    });
```

**Html**

```
<label>Selected Area:
<span>
  <p id="selectedPart">Area</p>
  <p id="selectedColor">Color</p>
  <button id="search">Search</button>
  </br>
  <form action="show" id="form" method="get"></form>
  <select id="selectNii" form="form" multiple="yes"></select>
</span>
</label>
```

Comment: what is the id of select element

Comment: most probably id of select and button will be same .

Comment: Make sure the ids are not duplicated

Comment: Please check `search` id is `type=submit` and check `option runat=server is not true`

Comment: I already check for the same id and also for the type. How I check the option runat?

Comment: @AmitKumar, _"most probably id of select and button will be same ."_ this would not matter as only the first element with the id will ever be used by an id selector

Comment: You do not show any options in your select tag, Are you adding them dynamically? if so also show that code.

Comment: Yes I add dinamically. But I think that's not the problem because with Google Chrome everything works

Comment: Do you have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or live page so we can see a demonstration of this

Comment: Most likely the invalid use of [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) causes troubles in FF. "`Permitted content: Phrasing content, but no descendant label elements. No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed.`" You've labeled two controls and even a form : ). Browsers are treating invalid HTML different ways, that's why your code might work in Chrome.

Comment: Yes the label was the problem thank you @Teemu